# Close Tab Before Continuing

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

This for each statement is part of an Excel macro which sends personalized messaged via whatsapp using the whatsapp api links. I need to close the tab after each mesage is sent to avoid ending up with chrome with a ton of tabs opened.

```
For x = 2 To uf
telwhatsapp = a.Cells(x, "B")
textwhatsapp = a.Cells(x, "C")

mylinkwhatsapp = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & telwhatsapp & "&text=" & textwhatsapp
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink mylinkwhatsapp

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "(~)" 'énvia enter para enviar mensaje
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:18"))
ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "(~)"
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I tried adding this before Next x and it didnt work

```
ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "{%F4}"
```

Also tried this before Next x didnt work neither

```
ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "{^F4}"
```

Any help to close the tab before continuing with the next excel row?

Comment: Well, which is it vba or vb.net; two entirely different things.

Comment: its vba, i just added tags

Comment: The code I used for the answer works. However, you need to make sure that the Webbrowser/Chrome has focus whan pressing ALT+F4 or `"%{F4}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `%{F4}` Also, when calling sendkeys you should do it this way, `Application.SendKeys "%{F4}", True` so that excel waits for the sendkeys to finish executing.

I hope that helps

Comment: question: why would just F4 close the tab? when u need to do alt f4 to do it using keyboard?

Comment: Help, F4 by itself doesnt close the tab